# How to concat these Strings effectively in Java 8?

Tags: java, string, concatenation

I need a string as follows.

`s = "$.vars.start.params.operations.values"`

I've tried to write it like this:

```
String s = "$".concat(".").concat("start").concat(".").concat("params").concat(".").
concat("operations").concat(".").concat("values");
```

There's a chain of `concat` operations.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: `"$" + "..." + "..."`!? Or just have the plain string since there is nothing dynamic in the string anyway. Or [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

Comment: What's wrong with `"$." + start + "." + params + …` (assuming those are actually variables)?

Answer (score 2):

Never ever use `concat` like this. It is bound to be less efficient than the code the compiler generates when using `+`. Even worse, the code as shown (using only String literals) would have been replaced with a single string literal **at compile time** if you had been using `+` instead of `concat`. There is almost never a good reason to use `concat` (I don't believe I have ever used it, but maybe it could be useful as a method reference in a reduce operation).

In general, unless you are concatenating in a loop, simply using `+` will get you the most (or at least relatively good) performant code. When you do have a loop, consider using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're looking for Java 8 method [`String.join(delimiter,elements)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...)), which expects a delimiter of type `CharSequence` as the first argument and varargs of `CharSequence` elements.

```
String s = String.join(".", "$", "vars", "start", "params", "operations", "values");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a reason for using .concat? In this case, you would approach this by using something like `"$"+"..." etc.`

If you wanted to add a dynamic approach, I would recommend using variables instead. It would look like

```
String s = variable1 + variable2 + variable;
```

If you are looking for something a bit more than there is also the [String.join](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#join(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence...))